# Dimiss SVProgressHUD

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, progress

I have a webview to load on launch and have a SVProgressHUD to display while loading. This issue is when the load time takes long and the user backs off the view, I want to hide/dismiss the `SVProgressHUD`.

There is a built in function of dismiss. I tried to put the command in `viewDidUnload` but it does not work. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From SVProgressHUD project doc, to dismiss your HUD you need to call one of the following method:

```
+ (void)dismiss;
+ (void)dismissWithSuccess:(NSString*)successString;
+ (void)dismissWithSuccess:(NSString*)successString afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;
+ (void)dismissWithError:(NSString*)errorString;
+ (void)dismissWithError:(NSString*)errorString afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;
```

Dismiss it in `viewWillDisappear` method of your `UIViewController`, if it has not be dismissed earlier. `viewDidUnload` is called on specific memory condition (e.g low memory), instead `viewWillDisappear` is called whenever your `view`'s controller disappears from screen.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642980/ios-svprogresshud-doesnt-dismiss-when-user-moves-from-one-screen-to-another-in

Answer (score 0):

> Updated for swift 3:

If you want to dismiss SVProgressHUD after a specific time interval, then used below lines of code:

```
SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 25) // you can change the time interval as you want
```

//Enjoy..! 

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C** put the following code:

**Show Spinner:**

```
[SVProgressHUD show];
```

**Hide Spinner:**

```
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

and for **Swift 4** use the following code:

**Show spinner**:

```
SVProgressHUD.show()
```

**Hide spinner**:

```
SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
```

Is very simple, here is the full documentation: [SVProgressHUD Documentation](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD)

Regards!