# iOS: SVProgressHUD doesnt dismiss when user moves from one screen to another in IOS Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, svprogresshud

I have used SVProgressHUD for  progresshud. I found that SVProgressHUD doesnt dismiss when user moves from one screen to another. Its tedious to call `[SVProgressHUD dismiss];` in `-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` of every class so i want to find the better solutions. Currently i have implemented below code But I want to find some better methods

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
  [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

[SVProgressHUD in Git](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD).

I know To dismiss the HUD we need to call one of the following method:

```
+ (void)dismiss;
+ (void)dismissWithSuccess:(NSString*)successString;
+ (void)dismissWithSuccess:(NSString*)successString afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;
+ (void)dismissWithError:(NSString*)errorString;
+ (void)dismissWithError:(NSString*)errorString afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)seconds;
```

But I dont want to call `[SVProgressHUD dismiss];` in `-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` of every class   since writing same code in overall projects in each class is not good way of coding

Comment: Are you using storyboards? You could create a custom segue that removes the ProgressHUD if its visible, then set the segue type to that for each xib with a ProgressHUD.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a super class where every class that uses the SVProgressHUD inherit that class and in the super class you can do like this :

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
if([SVProgressHUD isVisible]) 
 [SVProgressHUD dismiss];}
```

Comment: isVisible or not is checked inside dismiss method in SVProgresshud

Comment: how can i call it in  all class

Answer (score 0):

**Objective C**

Write in **AppDelegate.m** file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    //add this line
    [SVProgressHUD setDefaultMaskType: SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
}
```

This code worked to everywhere in project.